# How can modify the windows service exe after its get stopped?

Tags: c#, windows-services, io

i have working in a windows application product ,here i need to replace the service exe(installation directory) for up-gradation ,so i had stopped the service and try to replace the exe by the given code

```
            ServiceController service = new ServiceController(servicename);

            service.Stop();

            service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped);

            Thread.Sleep(10000);

            System.IO.File.Copy(application.exe, newapplication.exe, true);
```

, its thrown a error as given below,

**The process cannot access the file 'C:\Program Files\Myapp\application.exe' because it is being used by another process.**

but i can sure my service dont having any dependencies ,i cannot find the way to replace the service file after getting stopped ,please help me to get out from the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how it works in C#, but in C++ you would definitively first need to unregister the service from the Services Control Manager (SCM) infrastructure before being able to remove the binaries.

Comment: Nope. Stopping the service and replacing the exe is enough.

Comment: thanks for this information. .NET hides these underlayer activities.

Comment: please leave the scm oriented concepts ,instead of that will see,what is the main reason against copy paste the service file after the service get stopped..

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to uninstall the service to upgrade it. I upgrade services via file copy often.

Try waiting up to 1 minute before copying the file.

Take a look at [wyUpdate](http://wyday.com/wyupdate/).  The AutoUpdater process is open source and you could see how they take care of it.  (I recommend the product anyway).

That said, there's no real magic to it; if you still can't copy over the .exe after a minute or so, something else is going on.